# Blazor App get data from external API on local machine

Tags: .net-core, blazor, local

I have built a fairly simple API, which is running on IIS on my local machine.  It works fine.  I then put an Ocelot gateway in front of it, which also works fine.  I now have a Blazor app that is supposed to get its data from this API, but it is just failing.  When this app runs using its own API it runs fine, so I know there is nothing wrong with my Blazor code.  Here is the line that fails using the Ocelot gateway:

```
customers = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://gateway.oracle.local/customers");
```

If I just paste that URL into my browser, it returns the data fine.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: TypeError: Failed to fetch
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.JSException: TypeError: Failed to fetch
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__13`1[[OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess.Models.Customer[], OracleWCON_V2.RODataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at OracleWCON_V2.Client.Pages.Customers.ListCustomers.OnInitializedAsync() in D:\source\repos\OracleWCON_V2_220512\Client\Pages\Customers\ListCustomers.razor.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

I get exactly the same error if I use the URL that goes directly to the API without the Ocelot gateway.  Just to re-iterate, if I use either of those URLs directly in my browser, I get the results I am expecting.

The fact it is a type error would lead me to think one of the fields in my Customer class was incorrect for the returned data, but I copied the class from the API, so I don't see how that could be true, but I stand to be corrected.

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Please include the actual calls from the network tab of your browsers tools. It might tell you a lot..

Comment: @BrianParker - Thanks for this, and I can now see the problem.  It is demanding that I issue the request via HTTPS, but this will only ever be for my personal use, which is why I just went with HTTP.  I am guessing there is no simple solution to this?

Comment: The simplest way is to make your app HTTPS.

Comment: @BrianParker - OK, the problem is clear now.  Because the API is based on microservices architecture, I have a number of sites on my IIS, using domain names I have just created in my hosts file.  So I don't have a valid certificate for customers.oracle.local in IIS, just one for my local machine.  Thanks for your input, I would never have got to the bottom of this without it!

Comment: Microservices have noting to do with this. You created bogus domain names but then forgot to create certificates for them. You can create multiple web apps or virtual directories under the same web app under port 80 and use the HOST header to allow the use of a friendly domain name for each of them. *Then* you need to map all of these domains to the IIS IP, typically using your DNS, not a hosts file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Instead of pointing out how stupid I am, which is already blatantly obvious, why don't you try suggesting something so I can fix the problem?

Comment: I've added the explanation in the comment. I didn't say stupid. I said this has nothing to do with microservices. Microservices is the name of a fashion trend, like `bell bottoms`. Mapping using HOST headers and DNS is as old as HTTP though.  I've been using host headers mapped to the same IIS server through AD DNS since 2007 when I first worked with SharePoint. It's a common way to generate friendly URLs for intranet portals, eg `https://finance` or `https://customersupport`. You can't do that with a `hosts` file though, because you can't modify `hosts` on all client machines.

Comment: This isn't even related to microservices, it's about SPAs and the APIs they cal. Even if you generate new certificates (as you should), your Blazor WASM will still fail because the *clients* won't know what IP to call. Besides, if you host all APIs on the same server, what's the point of using multiple host names? If you wanted to parameterize service URLs the easiest way is through Configuration, not by hard-coding URLs and switching them around using DNS. DNS changes have a very high latency - minutes

Comment: If you want to handle load balancing, failover or routing, you need a load balancer or reverse proxy. Instead of using specialized reverse proxy devices, you could use the [YARP Library](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/index.html) to create our own reverse proxy with just the features you need. Perhaps you only need to forward HTTP requests to different services. For high traffic services, the destinations could be load-balanced clusters of endpoints. These features are available as optional NuGet packages

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you for expanding on your answer, that is much more helpful.  The purpose of what I am doing is for demonstration purposes only, it will never go anywhere other than my local machine.  So I have generated a self signed certificate for customers.oracle.local and installed it in my Trusted Root Certificate Authorities Folder. When I go to the URL, Chrome presents me with a choice of 2 certificates for authentication, neither of which work, it just reverts to HTTP.

Comment: Perhaps that is to do with how I generated the cert, which was with this PowerShell script: New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "customers.oracle.local" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"  Then copying the cert from my local folder to the trusted one

Comment: To demonstrate a solution to a problem, you need to understand the actual problem. The problem with "microservices" is that it's a fashion name used by people that didn't want to say "services". *All* of the problems, solutions, techniques were available and used in service-oriented architectures. The only new thing is deployment through Docker. The people that used "microservices" to sell consulting though, couldn't say that so they rewrote the original advice as "best practices" and "pattern" articles with artificially restricted contents

Comment: Fascinating.  Not sure how your insight helps me to fix my problem though.

Comment: There *are* good books, guides and frameworks out there. The subject isn't trivial though. [.NET Microservices: Architecture for Containerized .NET Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/) is essentially an entire book. Different techniques are needed in different scales, and can actually become problems at the wrong scale. Using DNS for discoverability for example is good for *small* deployments, bad for a single server or lots of servers. People use Kubernetes because it abstracts routing but increases complexity

Comment: To solve your problem: Do you need custom DNS names in the first place? With a single server, not really. It's useful to see how things are done "the hard way" but something to be avoided if you can. If you want to test deployment to dozens of "machines" use a Kubernetes scenario. Or, to quickly test multi-service environments, use Dapr over Minikube (a single machine Kubernetes). The Dapr framework abstracts the connection between isolated services, which means you can get up to speed very quickly and test some complex scenarios

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you for your input, I will do some more reading up.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused because my API was running on HTTP, whilst my App was using HTTPS.  This caused my browser to block the app as it had mixed content, some HTTP and some HTTPS.  I still don't have this working due to certificate issues, but at least I got to the bottom of the original problem.